# Angularjs Nested ng-repeat with conditional caluse

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi i have situation were multiple ng-repeat are nested as

```
 <form  ng-repeat="pt in prolist">
Frequency <input  type="checkbox" ng-model="pt.req"  />
 <div ng-repeat="disc in prolist">
    ------
</div>
</form>
```

What I am trying to do is something like this

```
  <div ng-repeat="disc in prolist" where pt.id =disc.Pt_id>
```

Please let me know how to write this line of code in angularjs 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would basically turn that "where..." for into a filter pipe: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

E.g., try:

```
ng-repeat="disc in prolist | filter:{Pt_id: pt.id}" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter repeaters in AngularJS.
Try using filter, the following link displays how to use filters with ng-repeat.

[ng-repeat with filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_03)

Answer (score 0):

if your data set is huge then do the filtering in javascript and then push the objects to $scope.prolist to render that in view because filters affect the performance badly but for small data sets it is fine.